# Print attributes of Nokogiri::XML::Node only, without innerHTML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Does anyone know if there is a native method for printing the attributes of a `Nokogiri::XML::Node` without `innerHTML` or text content.

For example, given the following `Nokogiri::XML::Node`:

```
<div id="customer" class="highlighted">
  <h1>Customer Name</h1>
  <p>Some customer description</p>
</div>
```

I would like to print only:

```
<div id="customer" class="highlighted">
```

or

```
<div id="customer" class="highlighted"/>
```

or

```
<div id="customer" class="highlighted"></div>
```

I know I could simply loop through the list of attributes using the `attributes` method, but I was wondering if Nokogiri already supports something like this natively.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]". We'd like to see the minimal code you've written to solve this, along with an explanation why it's not doing what you want. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you. There are many examples of using Nokogiri here on Stack Overflow, and most of them will show how to access a node. From there it's a matter of removing the contents of the node and printing it as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @theTinMan, but I had read the instructions you cited long ago, prior to your post, and the code I posted was complete. I had tried many different things prior to asking the question, and posting them all would not have made my question unnecessarily long and confusing, it would also have made it much less helpful for other people seeking to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output the node with its content deleted:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(
  '<div id="customer" class="highlighted">
    <h1>Customer Name</h1>
    <p>Some customer description</p>
  </div>'
)

node = doc.at_css('#customer').clone
node.content = nil
p node.to_html
#=> "<div id=\"customer\" class=\"highlighted\"></div>"
```

Comment: This is actually quite clever. I ended up using `node.content = nil` because for me it didn't matter if I destroyed the original HTML fragment, and I didn't want to add extra overhead by cloning the element, but your code certainly does the job, and for small nodes this overhead would be quite small. Thank you, sir!